# How to reorder uitableviewcell without showing reorder control?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm using spliviewcontroller for my ipad application. I've also implemented reordering for the uitableview which on the left of spliview. What i want to achieve is user can reorder the tableCell but need not touch on the three white bars. User should be able to touch anywhere on cell and reorder it. Is it possible?

Comment: I ran into this answer, which may be of help... not an easy solution, but it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624730/reordering-uitableview-without-reorder-control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reordering UITableView without reorder control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624730/reordering-uitableview-without-reorder-control)

Answer (score 3):

The class below will hide the reorder control and make the whole UITableViewCell touchable for reordering. Additionally, it takes care of re-resizing the content view to its original size, which is important for autolayout.

```
@interface UITableViewCellReorder : UITableViewCell
{
    __weak UIView *_reorderControl;
}

@implementation UITableViewCellReorder

#define REORDER_CONTROL_CLASSNAME @"UITableViewCellReorderControl"

/*
 Override layoutSubviews to resize the content view's frame to its original size which is the size 
 of the cell. This is important for autolayout!
 Do not call this method on super, as we don't need any further layouting wihtin the cell itself.
 */

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self setAndHideReorderControl];
}

/*
 Find the reorder control, store a reference and hide it.
 */

- (void) setAndHideReorderControl
{
    if (_reorderControl)
        return;

    // > iOS 7
    for(UIView* view in [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:REORDER_CONTROL_CLASSNAME])
            _reorderControl = view;

    // < iOS 7
    if (!_reorderControl)
        for(UIView* view in self.subviews)
            if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:REORDER_CONTROL_CLASSNAME])
                _reorderControl = view;

    if (_reorderControl)
    {
        [_reorderControl setHidden:YES];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Touch magic

/*
 Just perform the specific selectors on the hidden reorder control to fire touch events on the control.
 */

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_reorderControl && [_reorderControl respondsToSelector:@selector(beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:)])
    {
        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        [_reorderControl performSelector:@selector(beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:) withObject:touch withObject:event];
    }

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_reorderControl && [_reorderControl respondsToSelector:@selector(continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:)])
    {
        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        [_reorderControl performSelector:@selector(continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:) withObject:touch withObject:event];
    }

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_reorderControl && [_reorderControl respondsToSelector:@selector(cancelTrackingWithEvent:)])
    {
        [_reorderControl performSelector:@selector(cancelTrackingWithEvent:) withObject:event];
    }

    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_reorderControl && [_reorderControl respondsToSelector:@selector(endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:)])
    {
        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        [_reorderControl performSelector:@selector(endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:) withObject:touch withObject:event];
    }

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Check out: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but here's a **Swift** helper that should help future adventure seekers.

```
/*
    THIS IS A HACK!
    It uses undocumented controls and class names, and will need to be revised with every iOS release.

    Usage:
        Call the 'transform' method after the cell is displayed - i.e. tableView(tableView: UITableView!, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell! ...

    Adopted from:
        http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point

    In case of failure: 
        - print names of all subviews
        - find the new 'UITableViewCellReorderControl' and reflect changes to the code below
*/
struct MovableTableViewCell {
    static func transform(cell:UITableViewCell) {
        var reorder = cell.getSubviewByName("UITableViewCellReorderControl")

        if (reorder == nil) {
            println("UITableViewCellReorderControl was not found. Reorder control will remain unchanged.")
            return
        }

        // resized grip
        var resized = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(reorder!.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(reorder!.frame)))
        resized.addSubview(reorder!)
        cell.addSubview(resized)

        // remove image
        for img:AnyObject in reorder!.subviews {
            if (img is UIImageView) {
                (img as UIImageView).image = nil
            }
        }

        // determine diff and ratio
        var diff = CGSizeMake(resized.frame.width - reorder!.frame.width, resized.frame.height - reorder!.frame.height)
        var ratio = CGSizeMake(resized.frame.width / reorder!.frame.width, resized.frame.height / reorder!.frame.height)

        // transform!
        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, ratio.width, ratio.height)
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -diff.width / 2.0, -diff.height / 2.0)
        resized.transform = transform
    }
}


extension UIView {
    func getSubviewByName(name:String) -> UIView? {

        if (object_getClassName(self) == name.bridgeToObjectiveC().UTF8String) {
            return self
        }

        for v in (self.subviews as Array<UIView>) {
            var child = v.getSubviewByName(name)

            if (child != nil) {
                return child
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very Nice , Why don't you make a library and host and mention in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I took the answer from ANami and merged it with another post to let it work with Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9 using Swift 2.2

I would suggest to use this as a base class:

```
    //
    //  MoveableTableViewCell.swift
    //  ReorderTableTest
    //
    //  Created by Geoff on 05/06/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Think#. MIT License, free to use.
    //

    import UIKit

    class MoveableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
        //self.showsReorderControl = false

        if (editing) {


            for view in subviews as [UIView] {
                if view.dynamicType.description().rangeOfString("Reorder") != nil {

                    // resized grip
                    let resized = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame)))
                    resized.addSubview(view)
                    self.addSubview(resized)

                    // remove image
                    for img:AnyObject in view.subviews {
                        if (img is UIImageView) {
                            (img as! UIImageView).image = nil
                        }
                    }

                    // determine diff and ratio
                    let diff = CGSizeMake(resized.frame.width - view.frame.width, resized.frame.height - view.frame.height)
                    let ratio = CGSizeMake(resized.frame.width / view.frame.width, resized.frame.height / view.frame.height)

                    // transform!
                    var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, ratio.width, ratio.height)
                    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -diff.width / 2.0, -diff.height / 2.0)
                    resized.transform = transform


                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote that will let you reorder the cells based on the user touching any part of the cell. I subclassed `UITableView` and used the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods to figure out what cell was tapped and move it back and forth. Its pretty basic code, let me know if you have any questions.

```
class ReorderTableView: UITableView {

var customView:UIImageView?
var oldIndexPath:NSIndexPath?

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch1 = touches.first else{
        return
    }

    oldIndexPath = self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touch1.locationInView(self))
    guard (oldIndexPath != nil) else{
        return
    }
    let oldCell = self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)

    customView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, touch1.locationInView(self).y - 20, self.frame.width, 40))
    customView?.image = screenShotView(oldCell!)
    customView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    customView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    customView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)

    self.addSubview(customView!)
    oldCell?.alpha = 0
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch1 = touches.first else{
        return
    }
    let newIndexPath = self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touch1.locationInView(self))
    guard newIndexPath != nil else{
        return
    }
    guard oldIndexPath != nil else{
        return
    }
    if newIndexPath != oldIndexPath{
        self.moveRowAtIndexPath(oldIndexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
        oldIndexPath = newIndexPath
        self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)!.alpha = 0
    }
    self.customView!.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, touch1.locationInView(self).y - 20)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.customView?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.customView = nil
    guard (oldIndexPath != nil) else{
        return
    }
    self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)!.alpha = 1
}

func screenShotView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {

    let rect = view.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,true,0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -view.frame.origin.y);
    self.layer.renderInContext(context!)
    let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return capturedImage
}

}
```