# iPhone: UITableView reorder rows

Tags: iphone

There is an edit mode in UITableView which gives user possibility to reorder rows. To reorder rows user should click and drag on edit button (3 stripes). Is there any possibility to reorder rows also when user touch on row at all, not only on edit button ??? Thanks...

Comment: Look at this question - [Reordering UITableView without reorder control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5624730/194544). Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically reorder rows (and in iOS 5 you can also reorder entire sections). You would just need to know where the user intends to move the row/section to based on the single tap. You need to use the methods

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

or

```
- (void)moveSection:(NSInteger)section toSection:(NSInteger)newSection
```

respectively.